# Two very similar Regex, other could not find match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match a shortName-field from a JSON'ish string (no longer in correct JSON format, thus regex).
Running regex here might not be the most efficient way. I'm open for suggestions, but **I WANT the solution for the original problem as well.**

**I'm using Python 2.7 and Scrapy, running PyCharm 2018.2**

**What I want:**
Get matches from the huge JSON'ish file full of restaurants, run every match into list, iterate the list objects and collect different fields data, which I set into variables for future use. We don't go that far here though.

I want to match the shortName-field, and pull out the value/data from it.

The code samples below start from the point where the huge file is already received (in unicode or string), and we start to match for restaurant specific data fields. In the actual pattern, I tried to escape, and not to escape, the " and : symbols.

**What I have:**
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6J2Wbt/1) (below)

**I got the actual regex which I'm trying to fix, which ends up in "NoneType has no attribute 'group'".**

**Do note, the first line "pattern" works, and brings me the data which I start to go through in for-loop. I don't believe that the problem lies there.**

```
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
for match in regex.finditer(r.text):
  restaurant = match.group()
  restaurant = str(restaurant)
  print restaurant
  print type(restaurant)

  name = re.search(r'(?<=shortName\":\")(.*?)(?=\")',restaurant,re.MULTILINE 
  | re.DOTALL).group()
```

Source sample:

```
156,"mainGroupId":1,"menuTypeId":1,"shopExternalId":"0001","displayName":"Lorem Ipsum","shortName":"I WANT THIS TEXT HERE","streetAddress":"BlankStreet 5","zip":"1211536","city":"Wonderland",
```

**Testing regex, which works for a fixed source sample.**
NOTE: The source sample for this one was formatted with \ by regex101, as I first had every " and : escaped with .
I copied this straight from their code generator, but it does work in code:

```
testregex = r'(?<=shortName\"\:\")(.*?)(?=\")'

test_str = (


156,\"mainGroupId\":1,\"menuTypeId\":1,\"shopExternalId\":\"0001\",\"displayName\":\"Lorem Ipsum\",\"shortName\":\"I CAN GET THIS MATCHED \",\"streetAddress\":\"BlankStreet 6\",\"zip\":\"2136481\",\"city\":\"Wonderland\")

matches = re.search(testregex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL).group()
print matches
restaurantname = matches
```

**What is the problem:**
The upper regex prints out the *"'nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'"*-error.
The lower regex gets me the data I want, in this example it prints out "I CAN GET THIS MATCHED"

I am well aware that there might be small syntax problems, as I've been trying to fix this for some time.

Thank you in advance. The more detailed answer, the better. If you got different approach to the problem, please do give code so I can learn from it.

Comment: `r'(?<=\"\:)(.*?)(?=\,\"shopID)'` I believe the "shopID" here is costing you the match.  Nonetype object has no attribute group simply means your regex engine failed to find a match

Comment: That pattern works actually, it brings me the restaurant-specific data. The problem is somewhere in the for-loop, and occurs on this line:
    name = re.search(r'(?<=shortName":")(.*?)(?=")', restaurant, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL).group()

Comment: In that case, maybe just enclose your logical block in an if-else statement. If object is Nonetype just continue with the iteration

Comment: Your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hbyXZf/1) does not match your string. There is no `shopID` in the input. Use [`shortName":"([^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/hbyXZf/2). See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/VqE5q3).

Comment: I would very much like to do that, but I should be able to match the shortName-field for every restaurant there is. I checked the whole source file, and I get as many shortNames as I get displayNames

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/VqE5q3

Comment: I assume that there's a "shopID" attribute in your file since you mentioned that you're able to find a match. Is there at least one "shortname" attribute for each shopID match that you find?

Comment: Yes, thank you both. Indeed, of course the lower testing regex worked, as it had nothing to do with the broken pattern, that feeds the source data for the upper regex. I'm now trying to figure out printing out the values of the iterator objects. Do you guys have any ideas, should I stick to finditer, or use something else?

Comment: Could you clarify what output you need? Why "printing out the values of the iterator objects" if you can get your matches directly with `regex.findall(s)`?

Comment: I could not get the regex.findall to work in my project, where finditer did the job immediately. I just want the values/data from the restaurant-specific fields in strings/int, depending on the field. I however did figure this out now, it works, and I thank you both. I was looking elsewhere, not realizing that the problem was indeed in the pattern (it was shopId, not shopID).

Comment: Shall I post https://ideone.com/VqE5q3?

Comment: Thank you so much, that is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hbyXZf/1) does not match your string. There is no `shopID` in the input.

You may get all your restaurant names directly with one `re.findall` call using the following regex:

```
shortName":"([^"]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbyXZf/3). **Details**

- `shortName":"` - a literal substring
- `([^"]+)` - Capturing group 1 (the result of the `re.findall` call will be the substrings captured into this Group): 1 or more chars other than `"`.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VqE5q3):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'shortName":"([^"]+)')
print(regex.findall('156,"mainGroupId":1,"menuTypeId":1,"shopExternalId":"0001","displayName":"Lorem Ipsum","shortName":"I WANT THIS TEXT HERE","streetAddress":"BlankStreet 5","zip":"1211536","city":"Wonderland",'))
```

Comment: Thank you and @kerwei for your help in the comments, and in this answer. This is now solved, and I learned a lot more.